# Retrieving data from database to introjs using JSON

Tags: c#, javascript, html, json, intro.js

I am using IntroJs currently and using the JSON to call the introjs.
Is it possible to store data/text/info in database and using JSON to retrieve it from the database?

```
 <h2 id="welcomeMsg">Welcome back,<asp:Label ID="lbl_WelcomeName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> !</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
function startIntro() {
    var intro = introJs();
    intro.setOptions({
        steps: [
          {
              element: '#welcomeMsg',
              intro: "Welcome Message. <br /> <a onclick='this.firstChild.play()'><audio src='Audio/WelcomeBack.wav'></audio><font style='font-size:24px'>▸</font> Play Audio</a>"

          }
```

Here is how's my code like, I want to make it such that intro: "(Retrieve from database here)";

Comment: What is the database built on? SQL Server? Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: I am using MySQL with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. I will roughly describe two of them.

- Build a web service which retrieves data from an SQL database. Then serialize the results in a JSON format and return them to your client application. Since you use C#, I would suggest to build it in WCF. You could follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec).
- You could use a database storing data in json format directly. These databases are NoSQL databases and [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is one good example.

Hope I helped!